# At least how many numbers should be selected from the set {1, 5, 9, 13, ...125} to be assured that two of the numbers selected have a sum of 146?

Tags: sequences-and-series, combinatorics

I know the answer is 20 (says the answer key), but I'm not quite sure how it got it.

I also know that in the sequence, we can pair $21+125$, $25+121$, $29+117$... and so on to get a sum of $146$. From 21 to 125, there are 27 terms, which means there are 13 pairs in the set that make a sum of 146. From here, I don't know how to go on any further.

Comment: Since each number in your set is of the form $4k+1$ for $0\leq k\leq 31$, and the sum of two such number is of the form $2+4(k+m)$, you can reduce your problem to the following one: What is the minimal number of integers one must choose from the set $0,1,\dots, 31$ so that one is guaranteed to have a pair among them whose sum is $36$?

Comment: Hint:  there are 6 "unpairable" numbers, namely $\{1,5,9,13,17,73\}$.  In a bad case, you'll draw all of those.  Then you can draw one each from all possible pairs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a textbook case of the [Pigeonhole principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pigeonhole_principle). You already correctly identified that are 13 containers, each containing two numbers, such that selecting both numbers will yield a sum of 146: $\{21, 125\}, \{25, 121\},\dots, \{69, 77\}$. We also have 6 containers, each containing one number, that will never yield a sum of 146: $\{1\}, \{5\},\dots,\{17\}, \{73\}$.

So, if we select 19 numbers from these containers, we could get one from each of the first 13 and all 6 from the others, not yielding 146.

If instead we select 20 we have guaranteed that we will select 2 from one of the first 13, yielding 146.

Answer (score 2):

The numbers that *can't* be part of any pair summing to 146 are 1, 5, 9, 13, 17 and 73 -- there are 6 of these and in the worst case all of them will be selected. Thus, if you select 20 numbers, at least 14 of them will be chosen among the 2×13 numbers that form useful pairs, and by the pigeonhole principle at least one of the pairs will have both its members selected.

On the other hand, you *can* select 19 numbers such that no two sum to 146, for example all the ones from 1 up to 73.